# Whats the default encoding in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I need to interact with a third party soap service. I have a field named checksum, this field need to be exactly 32 bytes long. I've verified that when debugging this checksum byte array is 32 bytes long. But when setting up SoapUI to view the response, this checksum field is 64 characters long. What's going on between my client and the server side? It seems to me that the default encoding is Unicode hence the number of bytes has doubled. Is it possible to set the encoding of the raw soap message to be for instance utf-8?

Comment: is the third party service a WCF Service?

Comment: I have no idea. Probably some java application which I do not have any control over

Comment: Why do you care about the encoding? If you need to send 32 bytes, send 32 bytes. Other than that, the encoding is in the SOAP message. The xml header has it. if the other side of your conversation does not respect it... maybe it's time to tell them they s...hould improve.